# Rendering div in Firefox with incorrect width

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have a problem:
[image]

I set a style.width div in Firefox with 232.875px. When I inspect div I see that width value is 232.883px (larger than expected) but style="width: 232.875px" is set. In Chrome all working correct. What wrong with Firefox with this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with sub-sub-sub-pixel precision?

Comment: I try to set fields in row with 'width' value to achive all fields in row to be from left to right inline and to avoid free space beetwen fields.

Comment: In my opinion, relying on a 0.008 pixel difference is only going to introduce rendering bugs rather than fix anything.